# MKAnnotation and setCoordinate:

Tags: cocoa-touch, mkannotation

I have a custom class that conforms to the MKAnnotation protocol. An instance of this class is held by a viewController, along with an object of type MKMapView, called `_mapView`. I've set the viewController to be _mapView's delegate. In the custom class interface I've declared:

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
```

as it's required per the MKAnnotation protocol. I also `@synthesize` it in that same class's implementation. However when I send the following message from the viewController:

```
[_mapView addAnnotation:myCustomClass];
```

I get an error:

```
<NSInvalidArgumentException> -[myCustomClass setCoordinate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1479e0
```

If I go into my custom Class's implementation file and define

```
- (void) setCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)newCoordinate
{
    coordinate = newCoordinate;
}
```

then the annotation is added to the map successfully.

Shouldn't `@synthesize coordinate;` take care of the `setCoordinate:` method? It seems odd that I have to both `@synthesize` the coordinate as well as write the `(void) setCoordinate:` method.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you say

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
```

the "readonly" is telling the compiler to only create a getter method for your property, not a setter method.

Since CLLocationCoordinate2D is a C struct and not an object, you can use:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
```

if you want the compiler to automatically create both the getter and setter.